# Dynamically Sorted Bag of Sets in Java

Tags: java, sorting, dynamic

I have a set of sets, say

```
Bag<Set<Integer>> sets
```

I want to write a custom comparator to sort the sets by their sizes descendent, like so:

```
class SetComparator implements Comparator<Set<Integer>>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Set<Integer> i, Set<Integer> j) 
    {
        return j.size() - i.size();
    }

}
```

when I write

```
Bag<Set<Integer>> sets = new TreeBag<>(new SetComparator());
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>();
s1.add(3);
s1.add(4);
s1.add(7);
sets.add(s1);
Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<>();
s2.add(1);
s2.add(9);
s2.add(12);
s2.add(29);
sets.add(s2); // the order is [s2, s1]
s1.add(5);
s1.add(12); // the order is still [s2, s1]
```

It works when I insert a number of sets. But when their sizes change, the sorted order is not preserved.

Is there a way to keep the sets with respect to their sizes but sorted dynamically?

Comment: The only way to do that would be to keep them in a `List` and actually resort it every time.  There's no way to "notify" the bag that it has to resort itself.

Comment: Maybe I could create a `Thread` and each time I add an element to a set which is a member of `TreeBag<>`, I notify the thread?

Comment: If you have to do any explicit notification, then you should just be removing the set from the bag, modifying it, and re-adding it.  It's honestly going to be a mess any way you try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by allowing only special Sets to be aded to TreeBag that get `TreeBag` as parameter and call a sort method on Treebag when the Set changes. I've tried this and it works but it has so many drawbacks (only special Sets allowed, what if a special Set moves to another Treebag, etc.) that I would never use it in any generic piece of code, only exception would be when the code is very isolated.

The alternative is to move the responsibility of sorting the `Bag` to the code using the `Bag`. A simple utility method (easy to read, easy to maintain) would do it:

```
public class Bag<T> extends HashSet<Set<T>> {

public Bag() {
    super();
}

public List<Set<T>> sorted() {
    return sorted(new SetComparator<T>());
}

public List<Set<T>> sorted(Comparator<Set<T>> comparator) {

    ArrayList<Set<T>> l = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
    l.addAll(this);
    Collections.sort(l, comparator);
    return l;
}

static class SetComparator<T> implements Comparator<Set<T>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Set<T> i, Set<T> j) {
        return j.size() - i.size();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bag<Integer> b = new Bag<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    b.add(s1);
    s1.add(10);
    s1.add(11);
    Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    b.add(s2);
    s2.add(20);
    System.out.println(b.sorted());
    s2.add(21);
    s2.add(22);
    System.out.println(b.sorted());
}
}
```